# Speech recogition python stuck in listening

Tags: python, python-2.7, audio, speech-recognition

I am using a nextech desktop microphone for my input and I know it works because I tested it in settings. I am using python 2.7. When I execute the code below, the script is like stuck at the `audio = r.listen(source)`. When I do a keyboard interrupt to terminate the script this is the traceback:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "test_audio.py", line 12, in <module>
    listen()
  File "test_audio.py", line 6, in listen
    audio = r.listen(source)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/speech_recognition /__init__.py", line 559, in listen
    buffer = source.stream.read(source.CHUNK)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/speech_recognition/__init__.py", line 161, in read
    return self.pyaudio_stream.read(size, exception_on_overflow=False)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pyaudio.py", line 608, in read
    return pa.read_stream(self._stream, num_frames, exception_on_overflow)
KeyboardInterrupt
```

And here is the code:

```
import speech_recognition as sr

def listen():
    r = sr.Recognizer()
    with sr.Microphone() as source:
        audio = r.listen(source)
    try:
        print(r.recognize_wit(audio, key="############################"))
    except sr.RequestError as e:
        return "There was an error with the speech recognititon software."

listen()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This might be interesting to you:

> *The recognizer tries to recognize speech even when I’m not speaking,
>   or after I’m done speaking.*
>
> Try increasing the `recognizer_instance.energy_threshold` property. This
>   is basically how sensitive the recognizer is to when recognition
>   should start. Higher values mean that it will be less sensitive, which
>   is useful if you are in a loud room.

Source: https://pypi.python.org/pypi/SpeechRecognition/

Answer (score 0):

This is the solution:

```
print("Speak something")
audio = r.listen(source)

try:
    said = r.recognize_google(audio)
    print(f"You said: {said}")
except Exception as e:
    print(f"I think you are at very noisy place,\nThis is the error in computer languge: {str(e)}")
```

In line where "audio = r.listen(source)" is written, You have to just add another parameter "phrase_time_limit=5". It will look like this:

```
audio = r.listen(source,phrase_time_limit=5)
```